# Software design: too many static objects?

Tags: design, design-patterns

### About the subject

I hesitated for a while between using singletons objects or plain static ones.  After having read a lot of different opinions, I made mine:

> If you don't need to prevent multiple creation of an object, don't use a singleton.

Therefore I used mostly static objects.

### Context

My program is a complex scientific program. It must communicate with the outside world (using zmq), output some logs and time itself to be sure that everything is fine.

### What I did

#### Logger

I dealt with the logs by creating/destroying the Logger object each time I need it. Static functions like

```
Logger::log() << "My Log";
```

construct the object, and at destruction (end of calling function) the log is output. **And this is fine!**

#### Zmq

Because it's needed everywhere in the code, the class implementing zmq cannot be owned by one object. I therefore access to a static object created above the `main()` function.

#### Timers

Again my timers must be able to time over several functions and be printed all at once for easier diagnostics: same solution for me, a static `TimerList` object containing all timers used.

### The Question

Now that you know as much as I do about my project: is it a bad design?

What would you do instead? Singletons ? Something else?

### Here is my main.cpp

```
bool READONLY;

// Must be started first to be deleted last.
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq_ext::socket_t logSocket(context, ZMQ_PUB);
namespace TimingModule{
   TimerList tm;
}

//Must be static so that exit() do a proper deletion.
static App app;

namespace Messenger {
    Messenger messenger(context);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   return app.run()
}
```

---

There is no exact answer because it's more set of advises and good practices: compiling the insightful comments would make a good answer. It helped a lot. Thanks!

Comment: What makes me think that it's a bad design is that objects have now several calls that seems to come from somewhere unknown (not a method, not a member function...)

Comment: Maybe it belongs to codereview? I don't know

Comment: Code review would require more than just a main.cpp, since otherewise there's no code to review, only a design to review, but if you can reduce your program to something that'll fit in one post feel free to post there.

Comment: First thought: If the only thing your main() does is app.run(), why not make these globals members of App? Also, why do you need to support exit()?

Comment: Dependency Injection

Comment: Does the program work?  Does it have any performance or maintainability issues?  Can other programmers understand it?

Comment: Most of the time when you want a singleton or static instance of a class you can move it into a class that performs the same functionality at a higher level. I don't know what zmq is so FWIW: For example, zmq:: socket_t can be moved into a Communications class and the fact that you using zmq or even sockets is hidden from the rest of the application. Also, I prefer a static interface to a log class initialized at startup rather than creating it each time and opening the file and closing the file or having to pass the instance around. It makes temporary logging for debug far easier.

Comment: @Ixrec: The main() does mostly this yes, I need to to support exit()  because a requirement is to be able to kill the app with CTRL+C

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Could you be more specific? I'm not familiar with code injection. I'll read about this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The program works, has good performance and is overall very maintainable. The question goes with "maintainable enough?" "understandable enough"? Somehow I'm nit-picking but it a way to learn more

Comment: @Dunk: very interesting. For the logger, I inspired myself from the \qDebug() << "mydebug"` function in Qt. About the sockets and timers: If I need to access the server info regularly from several parts of the code, or to measure the time of several parts of the code, would you do a singleton? How could you put that in a class that does the same thing in a higher level (it's already in a class but with a static object of it used everywhere). I sadly can't provide a simple code, because the issue appear with the program grows in complexity.

Comment: I can only guess what "server info" and "measure the time" means in your case. But if server info is mainly constant data then I'd initialize that first and I would only pass the data that each class needs when creating the classes that use the server info data. If ServerInfo changes a lot then I'd possibly have ServerInfo signal change events for the info of interest and have the other classes handle those events. For measure time, I don't know what you mean other than something like this, startTime = RTC.GetTime();  // do some stuff; endTime=RTC.GetTime(); totalTime=endTime-startTime;

Comment: "Would you do a singleton?". I have not used a true singleton in at least a decade. Once I learned how to do a decent OO design it became obvious that singletons are only needed for very rare special cases. Usually, the one and only instance is created at application startup and it is passed around to those who need it. That one instance doesn't get deleted until the app exits. No singleton implementation necessary. If that one instance gets created/deleted multiple times during the app life then singleton applies. I haven't run into needing that yet even after hundreds of thousands of SLOC.

Comment: @Dunk Exactly. If a global object is appropriate, call it a global, don't pretend it is a singleton.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say you're using bad design.  There is always a cost in coding--to win the most 'CS class' worthy / most object-oriented award isn't really what coding is about.  Code is a tool, just like any other and like most tools--you invent uses for those tools as needed.

I find it easier myself to use a static class for 'utility' type stuff as you have here and then unstatic them.  In essence you then just need to now keep track of when they're created, destroyed, and which one you're referencing instead of rebuilding a singleton class, which has a much different format.  The way I tend to build my static classes are pretty similar to how I treat objects anyway, minus some of the bookkeeping--so it's more readily scaleable.

In short--if you didn't need to complicate your product and saved time with your solution, there's no problem at all with what you did.  As you get more experienced you'll learn how to keep your code manageable so that if you do need to scale it and unstatic your classes, you already have built your template for how 1 works in a bubble.

There is no greater punishment, however, for having built a very unscalable solution and your boss tells you the next day to have it support x1000.